# Print is rotated perfectly on bed, while straight in the slicer. X-axis moves slowly while printing a straight Y-axis line

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, troubleshooting, octoprint

I have a weird problem that I can't seems to find an answer for.

I'm using SuperSlicer with my Ender3 + OctroPrint setup.

The prints on the bed in SuperSlicer is perfectly straight

[image]

However, it seems that when my printer is moving in a straight Y-axis line, there is some kind of linear multiplier on the X-axis because it moves slooowly to the side causing the print to be pretty perfectly rotated on the physical bed as seen in Octoprint and also on the real physical bed (luckily my physical bed is slightly to large so I don't go outside of it).

[image]

I know there is some kind of setting for this which is used for Z-offset with probe, but I can't seem to find it, and it seems weird that it has been set for the X and Y axis. I don't know if that is what really causing this, because I've never touched those settings on this printer before

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Would you consider using a brim rather than a skirt ?  That should print some laps around each part before starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The print is **not rotated at all** on the print bed, the OctoPrint image is exactly the same as the image of SuperSlicer.

What you see is the skirt being printed misleading you into thinking the whole print is rotated! As the rectangles in the corners are aligned in the middle of the rectangles, the skirt is made of 4 skew lines.

If this print prints outside of the bed (in your case the bed is large enough to not cause problems) you are facing the issue that the print bed is incorrectly centered (the hotend to be precise). To have your prints print in exactly the same position as you slice them in the slicer, you could look into [How to center my prints on the build platform? (Re-calibrate homing offset)](/q/6375), this describes how to determine the offsets from the end stops should be set to get the center of the slicer in the center of your printer.

Comment: Haha your are absolutely correct  I never realized.... The skirt is slightly skewed because not all rectangles are rotated the same, exactly as you say. Thanks!